# Sleep command in sh with variables

Tags: shell, unix, sleep

I was wondering how I can make my shell script sleep for the sum of my variables, thanks!

```
#!/bin/sh
echo hello1
a=6
b=2
c=3
d = $a+$b+$c
sleep $d
echo hello2
```

Answer (score 8):

As others have indicated, the *modern*(*) approach is to use `#!/bin/bash` or even `#!/bin/ksh` with their built-in support of arithmetic operations using `n=$(($a+$b+$c)`.

As you have explicitly mentioned `#!/bin/sh`, here is a solution that will work for you.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo hello1
a=6
b=2
c=3
d=`echo "$a+$b+$c" | bc`
sleep $d
echo hello2
```

The key part is using backquotes for command-substitution, and sending the math arguments to be evaluated by the `bc` command, using the shell's pipe (`|`) functionality: i.e.

```
d=`echo "$a+$b+$c" | bc`
 |  |       |      |  | -> bc is a "basic" calulator
 |  |       |      | -> pipes pass std-out from preceding cmd, to std in fo following cmd
 |  |       | -> a string to be passed to `bc` for arthimetic evaluation
 |  | -> echo writes its output to std-out 
 | -> = assigns output of cmd=substition to var $d
```

*(*) modern in shells means 1986 and later ;-)*

IHTH

Answer (score 1):

You can do arithmetic with `$((...))`:

```
d=$(($a + $b + $c))
```

Comment: I tried that but I'm getting syntax errors? sleep.sh: line 6: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
sleep.sh: line 9: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Ignore that last comment^ This is the error it is giving me 
") 3ntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "

Comment: @KW1: Try changing `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello1";
a=6;
b=2;
c=3;
d=$(($a+$b+$c));
sleep $d;
echo "hello2";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
    a=6
    b=2
    c=3
    ((d=a+b+c))
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make a variable time ranging from seconds to hours, one way is to do that by using for loops. In this way, the whole time should be elapsed through three for loops, each of which elapsing seconds, minutes and hours separately. The following is the bash code :

```
echo -n "enter seconds:"
read sec
echo -n "enter minutes:"
read min
echo -n "enter hour:"
read hour
for ((i=0; i<$sec;i++))
  do
     sleep 1
  done
for ((i=0;i<$min;i++))
  do
     sleep 1m
  done
for ((i=0;i<$hour;i++))
  do
    sleep 1h
  done
```

the “sec”, “min” and “hour” are the variable into which the whole time has divided.